# Create custom Notice-Type, and use it on specific actions(i.e add to cart button)/pages in woommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wish to create a custom "notice-type" in Woocommerce.

The default templates used for messages are: 'Success', '*Error*' & '*Info*'.

I have created a Template in the Override folder of my theme -> woocommerce/notices/"my-notice.php"

How should I override, in my theme "functions.php" file the default call for '*Success*' notice-type in product-page-> add-to-cart button after submit, to use the custom notice-type->"my-notice.php" ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is even later but I have found the exact solution you are looking for: a custom notice (type) for the add_to_cart action.
I couldn't find it elsewhere so dropping it here just in case.

### Creating the notice

**First**, let WooCommerce know you have a new [notice_type available](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_notice_types/):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_notice_types', function($notice_types) {
  $notice_types[] = 'mynotice';
  return $notice_types;
}, 10, 3);
```

**Second**, create the notice template file in `/woocommerce/notices/mynotice.php`
For example, copy the success notice and rename it and change the HTML a bit:

```
<?php foreach ( $notices as $notice ) : ?>
<div class="mycustomnotice" <?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr( $notice ); ?> role="alert">
  <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now you can use your custom notice (anywhere) with the following code, just make sure the WC `woocommerce_output_all_notices` action has been hooked.

```
wc_add_notice( 'my message here', 'mynotice' ); 
// parameters: message html, notice type, notice data attributes
```

---

### Using custom notice for the add_to_cart action (overwrite)

So now we have our notice working, start looking for the correct filter to alter the default message (in this case the add-to-cart message).
Found here: [WooCommerce Github v4.0](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/4.0/includes/wc-cart-functions.php#L133), so let's change it:

```
add_filter('wc_add_to_cart_message_html', function ($message, $products, $show_qty) {
  return '<p> my custom notice html </p>';
}, 10, 3);
```

Or more advanced using a custom php template:

```
add_filter('wc_add_to_cart_message_html', function ($message, $products, $show_qty) {
    ob_start();
    wc_get_template('mycustom/path/to/mynoticehtml.php');
    $notice_html = ob_get_clean();
    return $notice_html;
}, 10, 3);
```

All done! Cheers.

EDIT:
If you just want this specific notice for a one time use you can skip the message_html filter and simply drop your message in the mynotice.php template. (less dynamic though)

Comment: Hi mate thanks for this. Can you elaborate something for me? I have been struggling to find where the appropriate place to use `the wc_add_notice` function. So far I have got everything working by adding an action to `wc_add_to_cart_message_html` -- is this the correct method of use? 

thanks again.

Comment: Hey @MakingStuffs, np, I don't really understand what you are looking for. Are you trying to add a custom notice? My answer is only to hook in the existing WC notices. If you want to add a custom one you should create a new question or browse the docs ;)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I was simply just playing around trying to customise the notice which was returned by the add_to_cart hook. In this case would you say my approach was correct? Thanks again mate.

Comment: Yeah sounds about right! @MakingStuffs. But to be absolutely sure to not override all WC notices with that type it is a best practice to create your own type with the woocommerce_notice_types filter.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a waaay late answer, but!
Try adding:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_notice_types', function ($notice_types) {
    $notice_types[] =   'warning'; // your custom type = custom template name
    return $notice_types;
});
```

to your `function.php`. This will let WC add your custom type to the "notices-to-be-printed" list.

Then use it as usual:

```
wc_add_notice("my new notice type here!", 'warning');
```

BTW, i would avoid special characters in your custom type name.
BTW! actually i'm not able to make it behave exactly like other types: i.e, when i update cart quantities, my custom notice-type message is not updated, while the original types are (?).

**EDIT**
Wow, i think i partially misnderstood your question..
Maybe the best way to achieve your goal is via CSS (if you want to change aspect) or using one of these hooks: `woocommerce_add_message` and `'woocommerce_add_' . $notice_type` (if you want to modify/filter the message).