# Customizing a WooCommerce notice with add_filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to customize a WooCommerce notice.
This is the notice I am trying to replace:

```
wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s has been removed from your cart because it can no longer be purchased. Please contact us if you need assistance.', 'woocommerce' ), $_product->get_title() ), 'error' )
```

Based on this helpful answer [WooCommerce Notice Messages, how do I edit them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188946/woocommerce-notice-messages-how-do-i-edit-them/26228345#26228345), I came up with this:

```
function my_woocommerce_membership_notice( $error ) {
    if ( '%s has been removed from your cart because it can no longer be purchased. Please contact us if you need assistance.' == $error ) {
        $error = '%s has been removed from your cart because you added a membership product. Please complete the membership purchase first.';
    }
    return $error;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'my_woocommerce_membership_notice' );
```

This results in HTTP500 errors and I can't figure out why exactly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching about this question in internet, it appears that a lot of people have serious similar error issues trying to use similar things…

This error message is set in [**includes/class-wc-cart.php**](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L238) at line 238.

Looking at WC version 2.6 source code in [**includes/wc-notice-functions.php**](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-notice-functions.php#L75), `wc_add_notice()` is handling 2 variables: `$message` and `$notice_type`.

So here for **$message** variable we have: 
`sprintf( __( '%s has been removed from your cart because it can no longer be purchased. Please contact us if you need assistance.', 'woocommerce' ), $_product->get_title() )`
**Instead of only:** 
`'%s has been removed from your cart because it can no longer be purchased. Please contact us if you need assistance.'`

**`%s`** is a string variable used by `sprintf()` to be replaced by **`$_product->get_title()`** value. But you can't use **`%s`** here anymore. 
This could be a reason for your error issue. Instead of `'%s has been…` try `'An item has been…`.

Then based on [**this thread**](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-checkout-error-messages-for-required-fields), using `strpos()` php function inside the condition, I have compiled this snippet, Without any guaranty:

```
function my_woocommerce_membership_notice( $message ) {
    if (strpos($message,'has been removed from your cart because it can no longer be purchased') !== false) {
        $message = 'An item has been removed from your cart because you added a membership product. Please complete the membership purchase first.';
    }
    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'my_woocommerce_membership_notice' );
```