# removing a specific notice from woocommerce cart/checkout

Tags: php, woocommerce

How do I remove the following notice from the cart: Checkout is not available whilst your cart is empty.

i guess it's something in functions.php but it's a mystery what that might be :)

I have looked around, I see many similar questions but nothing for that notice so far.

Comment: Have a look at the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?q=Checkout+is+not+available+whilst+your+cart+is+empty) when your search for that string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WooCommerce Notice Messages, how do I edit them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188946/woocommerce-notice-messages-how-do-i-edit-them)

Comment: sadly not. The problem is I don't know what to replace 'wc_add_to_cart_message' with. Maybe wc_cart_is_empty? but that doesnt seem right

Comment: Have a look at my first comment. I linked you the GitHub Search for the string. There you'll find `woocommerce_checkout_redirect_empty_cart `